# ¿Cómo puedo superponer imágenes puestas cómo background con Bootstrap y CSS?

Tags: css, bootstrap, imagen, background

estoy haciendo una página web, y la mayoría de las imágenes las estoy colocando como background-img, pero varias de estas imágenes deben ir superpuestas solamente por los bordes superior e inferior, ya que tienen un borde en zigzag sobre estos bordes (superior e inferior), que la primera imagen por ejemplo: en su borde inferior debe tener superpuesta la segunda imagen por la parte de su borde inferior (la imagen del zigzag) debe de ir encima de otra que no tiene ese borde, ya intenté poner los background-img con posición absoluta, relativa, les he puesto diferentes "top" para hacer que la imagen suba o baje sobre de otra imagen, también la he puesto en el HTML, fuera del contenedor padre que contiene a la primera imagen, y no logro hacer que ambas imágenes se superpongan por el borde, también he usado z-index y posición absoluta. Les comparto una imagen y parte de mi código, por favor les pido ayuda llevo bastantes días con esto y no lo he podido solucionar. Soy nueva en esto, perdón. Mil gracias a quien pueda ayudarme. Puse el css en una imagen,porque me marcaba un error stackoverflow al subir otro fragmento de código.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4EF6.png]

```
<body>
<!--  ARCHIVO CREADO PARA PROBAR LAS IMÁGENES RECORTADAS JNRI -->
<header class="bg-header">
    <div class="container h-100">
        <!-- Nav -->
        <nav class="text-center">
            <!-- Logo -->
            <div class="logo h1 text-white py-1">
                <img src="./img/LOGO.png" width="136px" height="89px" alt="">
            </div>
            <hr class="text-white" />
            <!-- Link items -->
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <!-- Social -->
                <ul class="nav social-networks mb-2 d-flex">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="" class="nav-link text-white">F</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="" class="nav-link text-white">T</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="" class="nav-link text-white">Y</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- links -->
                <ul class="nav m-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 d-flex">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active text-white" aria-current="page" href="#">Inicio</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" role="button"
                            data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            Nosotros
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li>
                                <hr class="dropdown-divider" />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Productos</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-white">Contacto</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- BTN -->
                <!-- <form class="boton" role="search"> -->
                    <!-- <button class="btn btn-success" id="btn-header" type="submit">
                        Haz tu pedido
                    </button> -->
                    <button class="boton">Haz tu pedido</button>
                <!-- </form> -->
            </div>
        </nav>

        <!-- Intro -->
        <div class="text-center h-50 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-column">
            <p class="color-text text-uppercase fw-light mb-1">
                Bienvenidos a nuestra web
            </p>
            <h1 class="text-white mb-5">El sabor tradicional <br> del cacao</h1>
            <br>
            <button class="btn btn-warning text-uppercase">Ver más productos</button>
        </div>

        <div class="row mt-1">
            <div class="col"></div>
            <div class="col text-center">
                <img src="./img/Rectangle 78@2x.png" alt="" width="8px" height="8px">
                <img src="./img/cuadro_naranja_grande.png" width="14px" height="14px" alt="">
                <img src="./img/Rectangle 79@2x.png" alt="" width="8px" height="8px">
            </div>
            <div class="col"></div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-3">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
                        <div class="container-fluid text-white">
                            <a class="navbar-brand text-white" href="#">
                                <img src="./img/Group 86@2x.png" alt="">
                                Productos
                                <div class="w-100"></div>
                                <div class="col-4">100% natural</div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
    
    
                <div class="col-3">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
                        <div class="container-fluid text-white">
                            <a class="navbar-brand text-white" href="#">
                                <img src="./img/Group 83@2x.png" alt="">
                                Empresa de
                                <div class="w-100"></div>
                                <div class="col-4">mujeres poblanas</div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
    
                <div class="col-3">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
                        <div class="container-fluid text-white">
                            <a class="navbar-brand text-white" href="#">
                                <img src="./img/Group 108@2x.png" alt="">
                                Personalización
                                <div class="w-100"></div>
                                <div class="col-4">de sabores</div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
    
                <div class="col-3">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
                        <div class="container-fluid text-white">
                            <a class="navbar-brand text-white" href="#">
                                <img src="./img/Group 88@2x.png" alt="">
                                Envíos a <br> domicilio
                                <!-- <div class="w-100"></div>
                                <div class="col-4"></div> -->
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
</header>
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DurB.png]